# Using Excel to create part numbers based on 4 levels of categories that each have unique identifiers based on the category combinations

Tags: php, mysql, excel, vba, categories

I am using Excel 2010 and have a list of products (~8000) that I need to create product code / part numbers for. These product numbers need to be based on 4 levels of categories, where each category has a code (2-3 digits of numerical values). For example:

- Model01: 15

  - Primary Category01: 11

    - Secondary Category01: 45

      - Tertiary Category01: 22
  - Primary Category02: 22

    - Secondary Category02: 50

      - Tertiary Category02: 23

So for example says Product A has the categories of Model01 > Primary Category01 > Secondary Category01 > Tertiary Category01 it would have a product code of 15-114522. I have this where it works in Excel. HOWEVER, at the end of each "Category Code" I also want to have a unique number to differentiate products in the same category combination. So I would want Product A to have a product code of 15-114522-XX (XX being a unique identifier number that auto increments only for that combination of categories). So 15-114522-XX and 15-123456-XX could both use 15 in the place of XX.

So far I have tried finding the duplicates using COUNTIF and then ranking them sequentially so that each category code that was duplicated was ranked with a unique number, but that ranked all duplicates (different category combinations that were both duplicated. I found the formula to rank sequentially here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152567/en-us

So I need a way to generate existing part numbers and a way to continually generate new part numbers if we add products.

I really feel like Excel is not the best way to do this, so if you have another suggestion for a way to do it I would be glad to hear it. I know some PHP, so if I could use PHP and MySQL Database that would be fine. I feel like this might need to use VBA to accomplish this through Excel(which I do not know, but I am sure I can figure out).

I realize that this is an extremely hard thing to understand so I will also link a Google Doc of the Spreadsheet where you can view it or download it if you would like.

**Google Spreadsheet**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlXmrYIdv91SdEFQVklURkdTZER0NFkxZ1B4ZFdZYXc

I would appreciate any and all responses. Let me know if you need anymore information and I will do my best. Thank you!

-Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd place another column right of "Part Number" labeled "Part ID". Place the following into the cell and drag it down to copy the code with the relative cell references.

```
=H2 & COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. That is what I was looking for. I do have to wait until I have all of my products have categories and then sort by the category combination before I add that formula otherwise they will change part numbers. Not a problem, though. Thanks!

Comment: Sorting by the P + S + T column shouldn't be necessary, but I guess it would make things look neater. If you are going to do that though, make sure to do a secondary sorting by the model column so that if you have the same parts, but for different models that they aren't mixed.

Comment: Mason, how exactly would I do it without sorting by the P + S + T column? That was the only acceptable method I could think of, though I am not exactly satisfied with it. Thanks again.

Comment: Well your goal was simply to make sure each part has a unique ID number, technically it doesn't matter in what order they are in, as long as they have a unique ID. But as I said its more esthetically pleasing to sort it on the excel sheet so I understand why you're doing it. Normally I'd be uploading the data to a mysql database where the order of entry doesn't really matter because you can retrieve it in any order you wish later on.

Comment: I am slightly familiar with using a MySQL database, mainly with PHP for creating a pseudo CMS for a website I built some time ago, but I am by no means fluent with it. What would be the best way to go about doing that? I am not sure how I would go about creating unique IDs and creating the category combinations. Would I need a table per primary category or just one table for categories? And would column names be what I have in the Excel file?

Edit: I am new to Stack Overflow. Should I create a new question or continue on here (since I really am wanting something different now, I suppose)?

Comment: I'll just answer it here as there isn't any private message system. You should probably first learn the structure of mysql databases and the mysql syntax for recalling that data. Then move onto how you'd recall that data using php's mysqli functions (mysql functions are becoming outdated). Personally I found "thenewboston"'s mysql tutorials on youtube very helpful for the mysql thing, it'll show you how to structure your tables properly, deal with unique IDs, etc.